# Angular dependent dropdown list

Tags: angular

I am getting the ID's in the console but how to get the names

in the console? I have two angular files mentioned below. It's actually

a dependent dropdown list concept where I have mentioned country, state & city.

I will be very grateful for your help.

register.component.html

---

Country:

<select *ngIf="getCountries()" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change)="onSelectCountry($any($event.target).value)" class="form-control input-lg" id="country" formControlName="country"

> 

Select Country
{{[country.name](https://country.name)}}

States:

<select *ngIf="states" [(ngModel)]="selectedState" (change)="onSelectState($any($event.target).value)" class="form-control input-lg" id="state" formControlName="state">

Select State
{{[state.name](https://state.name)}}

City:

Select City
{{[city.name](https://city.name)}}

register.components.ts

---

selectedCountry = 0;

selectedState = 0;

states= [];

cities= [];

onSelectCountry(country_id: number) {

this.selectedCountry = country_id;

this.selectedState = 0;

this.cities = [];

this.states = this.getStates().filter((item) => {

return item.country_id === Number(country_id)

});

}

onSelectState(state_id: number) {

this.selectedState = state_id;

this.cities = this.getCity().filter((item) => {

return item.state_id === Number(state_id)

});

}

getCountries() {

return [

{ id: 1, name: 'India' },

{ id: 2, name: 'USA' },

{ id: 3, name: 'Russia' }

];

}

getStates() {

return [

{ id: 1, country_id: 1, name: 'Bihar' },

{ id: 2, country_id: 1, name: 'odisha' },

{ id: 3, country_id: 2, name: 'Albama' },

{ id: 4, country_id: 2, name: 'Alaska' },

{ id: 5, country_id: 3, name: 'Moscow' },

{ id: 6, country_id: 3, name: 'Moscow oblast' },

]

}

getCity() {

return [

{ id: 1, state_id: 1, name: 'Patna' },

{ id: 2, state_id: 1, name: 'Amarpur' },

{ id: 3, state_id: 1, name: 'Begusarai' },

{ id: 4, state_id: 1, name: 'Bhagalpur' },

{ id: 5, state_id: 2, name: 'Bhubaneswar' },

{ id: 6, state_id: 2, name: 'Cuttack' },

{ id: 7, state_id: 2, name: 'Rourkela' },

{ id: 8, state_id: 2, name: 'Koraput' },

{ id: 9, state_id: 3, name: 'Arab' },

{ id: 10, state_id: 3, name: 'Argo' },

{ id: 11, state_id: 3, name: 'Athens' },

{ id: 12, state_id: 4, name: 'Big Lake' },

{ id: 13, state_id: 4, name: 'Craig' },

{ id: 14, state_id: 5, name: 'Annino' },

{ id: 15, state_id: 5, name: 'Bibirevo' },

{ id: 16, state_id: 5, name: 'Kotlovka' },

{ id: 17, state_id: 6, name: 'Beloomut' },

{ id: 18, state_id: 6, name: 'Biorki' },

]

}

Expecting names but getting Id's.

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz example pls. It'll help us to help you

Comment: You didnt even format the code

Answer (score 0):

Use this code ,it works :)

this is ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedCountry: any = {};
  selectedState: any = {};
  countries = [];
  states = [];
  cities = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countries = this.getCountries();
  }

  onCountrySelect(countryid) {
    this.selectedCountry = this.countries.filter(
      (item) => item.id == countryid
    );
    this.states = this.getStates().filter(
      (item) => item.countryId == countryid
    );
    this.cities = [];
  }

  onStateSelect(stateid) {
    this.selectedState = this.states.filter((item) => item.id == stateid);
    this.cities = this.getCities().filter((item) => item.stateId == stateid);
  }

  getCountries() {
    return [
      { id: 1, name: 'country 1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'country 2' },
    ];
  }

  getStates() {
    return [
      { id: 1, countryId: 1, name: 'state 1' },
      { id: 2, countryId: 1, name: 'state 2' },
      { id: 3, countryId: 2, name: 'state 3' },
      { id: 4, countryId: 2, name: 'state 4' },
      { id: 5, countryId: 2, name: 'state 5' },
    ];
  }

  getCities() {
    return [
      { id: 1, stateId: 1, name: 'city 1' },
      { id: 2, stateId: 2, name: 'city 2' },
      { id: 3, stateId: 2, name: 'city 3' },
      { id: 4, stateId: 3, name: 'city 4' },
      { id: 5, stateId: 3, name: 'city 5' },
      { id: 5, stateId: 4, name: 'city 6' },
      { id: 5, stateId: 5, name: 'city 7' },
    ];
  }
}
```

and in the html file:

```
<label>Country:</label>
<select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry.id"
  (change)="onCountrySelect($event.target.value)"
>
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
    {{ country.name }}
  </option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<div>
  <label>State:</label>
  <select
    [(ngModel)]="selectedState.id"
    (change)="onStateSelect($event.target.value)"
  >
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.id">
      {{ state.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div>
  <label>City:</label>
  <select>
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">
      {{ city.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I update the answer ,it works I test :)